# How to Secure Facebook Gallery Vote App

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have a database that contain Facebook users id, and a customized photo.

I want to run a **voting** competition where users can access a gallery(Facebook app) and vote.

How could i make this app, i know how use PHP/SQL query but i want it to be secure and not easy hackable?

Thanks

Comment: Oh! sure i will do, thank you for the hint :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the:

[PHP Security Guide by PHP Security Consortium](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/)

It covers various security concepts for you to get stared.

Comment: But... I was looking for an answer like using state parameter, tokens... and others Facebook API tricks....

Comment: @Armin: You should clarify your question initially :) or ask another question with all those details :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest storing all voter's Facebook UID's in a table. Then, you can check if a UID has voted before - if yes, then you can disallow that UID from voting again.

Unfortunately, there will always be a way to get around this - Facebook account-bot nets that can flood a user's votes, or one of those forums that allows users to trade voting favors with one another.

Comment: Actually I am not worried about fake accounts, I'm worry about hacking, specially tamper data technique, so hackers can stop the request and send other user ids